# Oracle SQL - Is it possible to lookup an Item Record's internal ID by matching the name from some given text?

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

Our company has multiple variations of SKUs depending on the country in which they are sold. For example, we may have:

Item #1: EXAMPLESKU
Item #2: EXAMPLESKU-CA
Item #3: EXAMPLESKU-UK

These variations only exist as a technicality, however the underlining products are identical.

I would like to show a saved search which has the domestic item as the key for each rown, and then I have Text Formulas that add the "-CA" and "-UK" (etc.) in their own columns to the right.

I would ultimately love to have links on all of those INTL columns which go to the INTL item record. So something like this:

<a href=**[INTL Item Internal ID Url]** target=_blank>'||**[INTL Item Name]**||''

The problem I have is I'm not sure how to use that text to lookup the Internal ID of the item record matching. For example, I need to take the text "EXAMPLESKU-UK" and somehow return "3". That way I can use it at the end of my item record URL.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at how to solve the problem; and the issues and errors with **YOUR** attempt. It is impossible for us to take a front-end issue (how to display a link to something) and provide you with a solution for a back-end issue (how to search for related items) when you do not give any details of the structure of your data/tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a match or filter by added country code (CA, UK) you can split the column text like below...

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ITEM", 'EXAMPLESKU'    "COUNTRY" FROM DUAL Union All
            SELECT 2 "ITEM", 'EXAMPLESKU-CA' "COUNTRY" FROM DUAL Union All
            SELECT 3 "ITEM", 'EXAMPLESKU-UK' "COUNTRY" FROM DUAL 
        )
Select
    ITEM "ITEM",
    COUNTRY "COUNTRY",
    CASE WHEN InStr(COUNTRY, '-') = 0 THEN COUNTRY ELSE SubStr(COUNTRY, 1, InStr(COUNTRY, '-') - 1) END "BASE",
    CASE WHEN InStr(COUNTRY, '-') = 0 THEN 'Some txt or Null' ELSE SubStr(COUNTRY, InStr(COUNTRY, '-') + 1) END "ADDTN"
From
    tbl
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--  
--        ITEM COUNTRY       BASE          ADDTN       
--  ---------- ------------- ------------- ----------------
--           1 EXAMPLESKU    EXAMPLESKU    Some txt or Null           
--           2 EXAMPLESKU-CA EXAMPLESKU    CA            
--           3 EXAMPLESKU-UK EXAMPLESKU    UK
```

The resulting dataset could be joined or filtered by ADDTN column to get and use the ITEM column. Regards....